# Using phanomJS, wait for effects of button click to finish before moving on

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am using `PhantomJS` to *crawl* a web page where I press a `button` to display some information, then take a screen shot.

The very simple code is below:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.settings.userAgent = 'useragent';
page.open('http://url', function() {
    page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js",   function() {
        page.evaluate(function() {
           $("#button_id").click();    
        });     

        page.render('clicked.png');

        console.log('Done!');
        phantom.exit();    
    });
});
```

The `button` click works, but the *rendering takes place too fast*. I want my script to *wait* a bit after it clicks the `button` to give the information enough time to be displayed.

I tried changing it to

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    page.render('clicked.png');

    console.log('Done!');
    phantom.exit();
}, 3000);
```

but that did not work.

How can I wait for the changes the `button` click has to take effect before I move on?

Comment: How did it "not work"?  Was there an error message?

Comment: Is CasperJS an option? Because [`casper.waitForSelector`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforselector)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` to check in regular intervals for the existence of an element that you know will only be there after the expected changes happened.

```
window.setInterval(
  function () {
    if (<some element is present>) {
      // do rendering
      // exit or clear interval
      } },
  3000 );
```